# How to extract a zip file inside a GitHub repository?

Tags: git, zip, github

GitHub GUI allows me to upload a zip file to a repository but it doesn't allow me to extract it.

I could upload the files directly (unarchived) but the problem is that some of the files are directories and the GitHub GUI doesn't allow uploading directories.

Is there a way to solve that problem from the command line?

Comment: Why can't you just commit the contents to the repository using git? Why this rigmarole of a zip file extraction and all that?

Comment: @muru I don't use Git... I wanted to commit from GitHub but as I have said, they don't allow to commit directories.

Comment: Well, using the `git` command is *the* command-line solution. If you won't do that, who knows what solution is valid here?

Comment: @muru I meant that I don't use Git generally so I don't know how to commit from Git itself (the only command I use with Git is `git clone`). I did imagine SSHing into my GitHub account somehow and do `unzip` there.

Comment: Please add that information to the question; it provides necessary context on what you try to achieve.

Comment: @AdminBee I disagree; I want to extract an uploaded file period, no "context" is necessary; if the community dislikes this question I urge it to lock it and delete it ASAP. Thanks for saving time to all parties.

Comment: Github is a service for hosting git repositories. It is meant for programming projects. git is a program for managing source code. Maybe you didn't know it, but when you are using Github, you are working with git repositories.

Comment: @Vilinkameni I know what GitHub is for; I host codes I have written in various computer languages there for years; I just generally don't work with Git, at least now.

Comment: Why not? It is the intended way to work with git repositories, and it is a CLI program. Unzip the files locally, then commit and push them to a repository. Otherwise, the answer to your question is: no, there is no other way.

Comment: @Vilinkameni because so far I used the GitHub GUI only ; it is indeed starting to be "not enough" for me and I will start to use git more often than just `git clone` here and there ; the answer is not necessarily "no" due to the GUI but I am sure we both agree that often the GUI just isn't the right tool for a certain action; furthermore, I have asked a better question about the topic here and got a wonderful answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/677499/uploading-files-some-of-which-are-directories-into-an-empty-github-repository

Comment: git manages files, not empty directories. [You cannot commit an empty directory to a git repository](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Can_I_add_empty_directories.3F).

Answer (score 5):

1. You **CAN'T** extract zip files in GitHub. Because it's a server for **storage** with no compute services, unless you use GitHub **Actions** [beyond topic].
2. You **CAN** upload directories and files without any problem (recursively), as long as you add them with `github add .` - the dot`.` is everything inside that directory.
3. If you download a zip file[comments] from GitHub `github clone` and then extract it, this was done in your computer [compute engine, CPU]:
   inside your directory do this:

   ```bsh
   git init
   git add .
   git commit -m "first commit"
   ```

   - `git init` start git and makes a directory called `.git`.
   - `git add .` selects all to be committed, including folders, files, everything.
   - `git commit -m` is to save that commit with a message.

   ```bsh
   git add origin master url_from_github_repository
   git push origin master
   ```

   - `add` is to tell git to add remote address[url-server].
   - `origin` is the name of the remote address [shortcut], this can be anything, so you don't have to type the **URL** every time [www.github.com/user/repo].
   - `master` is the name of the branch; you can have many branches, but `master` usually is the one you work with for changes.
   - `git push` is to upload your commit [everything] to your repository in GitHub.com [**server**].

###### Finally

There's another service provided by a third party to upload large files [images, videos, psd] to their server and keep tracking changes [git] of these files,  but **NOT** **upload** to GitHub.com. The name is `git lfs`. It is another program that uses git, and you need to install it first.
[git-large-file-storage](https://youtu.be/uLR1RNqJ1Mw)

Comment: Github provides Github Actions. And there is the possibility to run unzip in a script or a dedicated action like https://github.com/marketplace/actions/action-zip

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of this project:
https://unzipgit.github.io

**Explanation:**

Github does not provide an option to unpack the archive in the repository, but there is a solution. The problem can be solved using the Github API (https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents). Their API allows you to upload files to the repository. Of course, if we send an archive, the archive will be uploaded, but if we parse the archive and loop through it, we can send each file to its own repository.

In my personal experience I have encountered this problem. It turned out that the solution has been waiting since the very creation of Github. As it usually happens, rather than waiting for a large company to implement something, it is easier to do it yourself.

If we're talking about JavaScript, we can get the contents of a ZIP archive using JSZip (https://stuk.github.io/jszip/). To my surprise, a very handy library (special thanks for the choice of file reading mode). If we simplify it very much, then uploading an archive looks like this:

```
// reading the archive
zipFile = await zip.loadAsync(inputArchive, { binary: true });
// loop
for (const [p,f] of Object.entries(zipFile.files)) {
  // read as base64
  base64file = await f.async("base64");
  // upload to github
  await reqest("PUT",`${url}/${fileName}`,{content: base64file});
}
```

You can implement this yourself or use my solution that I made for myself. The logic is the same as I have already said. For convenience, I implemented the ability to send an archive from your computer or select an archive that is already in the repository. In both cases, the browser will load the archive and traverse it, sending each file to the repository.