# Uploading files, some of which are directories, into an empty GitHub repository

Tags: directory, git, github

I have created a program in my personal computer and I want to upload all its files into an empty GitHub repository.

I cannot do so from GitHub GUI because some of these files are directories and currently GitHub GUI rejects uploading directories.

Could I use Git to upload these files, perhaps by a "pull request" to the empty GitHub repository (which I would later approve from GitHub GUI)?

I would prefer a solution without SSH.

### Update

I was wrong, it **is** possible to upload directories to GitHub GUI directly;
It's just that the Windows 10 Home upload modal mislead me;
A GitHub support member used another upload modal (of Mac OS) which has a more intuitive upload modal instead the "Open" button in the Windows modal, but, after minimizing the modal I could drag the directory and upload it this way.
<sub>Marking the directory and click "Open" didn't cause uploading as it would with non directory files.</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you visit your empty repository on GitHub using a web browser, you’ll see instructions explaining how to populate it (see [this empty repository](https://github.com/skitt/empty) for example):

1. Prepare a directory containing everything you want to upload, if you haven’t already done so.
2. Initialise a git repository inside it:

   ```
   git init
   ```
3. Add all the files and directories, and commit this:

   ```
   git add -A
   git commit -m "Initial import"
   ```
4. Match the branch to that expected by GitHub:

   ```
   git branch -M main
   ```
5. Add your GitHub repository as a “remote” (this assumes you’ve set up an SSH key):

   ```
   git remote add origin git@github.com:roiko/foo.git
   ```

   (replace the URL as appropriate).
6. Push your contents:

   ```
   git push -u origin main
   ```

Comment: All of the program's files in my computer are already in a standalone directory but still, I don't want to upload that directory as a new repository, rather I want to upload all its files into an existing empty repository without SSH.

Comment: Nothing about my answer assumes a new repository, just an empty one.

Comment: You don’t *have* to set up SSH, GitHub will show appropriate instructions if you haven’t.

Comment: I mean, what is the meaning of `Initialise a git repository inside it` if the repository already exists in GitHub?

Comment: `Add all the files and directories, and commit this` because the files are already contained in the directory, I don't understand this saying (maybe you meant "add them all to Git").

Comment: `git init` is used to initialise a git repository locally — having a repository on GitHub isn’t enough, you need a local repository as well, either from a `git clone` or a `git init`. Then `git add` and `git commit` allow you to add content to the local repository, and `git push` pushes your local repository’s state to the remote repository (on GitHub).